# R Error: Wasn't able to determine range of domain

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

I randomly generated the following data :

```
x1 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x2 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x3 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x4 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x5 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x6 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x7 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x8 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x9 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x10 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x11 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x12 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x13 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x14 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x15 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x16 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x17 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x18 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x19 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x20 = rnorm(1,5,5)
```

Then I defined this function (Likelihood of a Normal Distribution):

```
  my_function <- function(mu,sigma) {

a = log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x1-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x2-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x3-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x4-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x5-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x6-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x7-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x8-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x9-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x10-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x11-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x12-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x13-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x14-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x15-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x16-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x17-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x18-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x19-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x20-mu)/sigma)^2))
}
```

However, the problem happens when I try to plot it:

```
library(plotly)

input_1 <- seq(-100, 100,1)
input_2 <- seq(-100, 100,1)


z <- outer(input_1, input_2, my_function)

plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

The following error is produced:

```
Error in scales::col_numeric(pal, rng, na.color = na.color) : 
  Wasn't able to determine range of domain
```

**Can someone please show me why this error is coming and what can I do to fix this problem?**

Comment: When I run your code, using `set.seed(42)` for comparability, I get `sum(is.nan(z))` equal to 109. Why are you using negative values for sigma? You will not be able to determine the range with `NaN` values in `z`. Below I will suggest some simplifications of your code.

Comment: @ dcarlson: Thank you so much for your reply! I also noticed an interesting problem : there are values on this graph that do not appear in the dataset! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71633672/r-points-appearing-in-graph-that-are-not-in-the-dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is pathological in two ways:

- a negative sigma is a problem
- a zero-valued sigma is a problem

So here is my updated code:

```
my_function <- function(mu,sigma) {

  
  a = log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x1-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x2-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x3-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x4-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x5-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x6-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x7-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x8-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x9-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x10-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x11-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x12-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x13-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x14-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x15-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x16-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x17-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x18-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x19-mu)/sigma)^2)) +
    log((1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)) * (exp((x20-mu)/sigma)^2))
}

library(plotly)

x1 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x2 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x3 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x4 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x5 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x6 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x7 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x8 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x9 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x10 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x11 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x12 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x13 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x14 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x15 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x16 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x17 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x18 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x19 = rnorm(1,5,5)
x20 = rnorm(1,5,5)

input_1 <- seq(-100, 100,1)
input_2 <- seq(1, 100,1)


z <- outer(input_1, input_2, my_function) 

plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

it gives me this plot:
[image: your plot showed up looking like this plot]