# Points Appearing in Graph that are Not in the Dataset

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, data-visualization, interactive

I am working with the R programming language.

I tried to plot the Likelihood Function of a Normal Distribution:

```
library(plotly)
y <- rnorm(5,5,5)

my_function <- function(x1,x2) {
    
    n = 20
    
    a = n/2*log(2*pi)
    b = n/2*log(x2^2)
    c = 1/(2*x2^2)
    d = sum ((y-x1)^2)    
    return (a + b + c* d)
    
}
input_1 <- seq(1, 10,0.1)
input_2 <- seq(1, 10,0.1)


z <- outer(input_1, input_2, my_function)

plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

As we can see here, there some values on this graph that are close to 100,000:

[image]

However, over the range at which this function was evaluated, the function can never take such a large value. For example, if I were to evaluate this function at the same point that appears in the above picture, I get a value that is nowhere close to 100,000

```
my_function(1, 7.1) 
[1] 59.94714
```

**Have I plotted this function correctly? Why does the value in the picture not match with the value I get from manually evaluating the function? Can someone please explain why this is happening and what I can do to fix this problem?**

Thanks!

**Note 1:**

- From a mathematics and statistics perspective, I don't think it is possible for the Likelihood Function of a Normal Distribution (for a small dataset generated from a Normal Distribution of mean = 5 and standard deviation = 5) could take such large values (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)
- I think the problem in this question is related to the `outer()` function - I don't think the correct values of the function are being calculated via the `outer()` function (e.g. take for instance the discrepancy between 59.9 vs 120,000)

**Note 2:An Alternate Plotting Procedure**

```
input_1 <- rnorm(10000, 5,1)
input_2 <- rnorm(10000, 5,1)

my_data = data.frame(input_1, input_2)


my_data$f = (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x1-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x2-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x3-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x4-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x5-input_1)^2))+
    
    
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x6-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x7-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x8-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x9-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x10-input_1)^2))+
    
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x11-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x12-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x13-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x14-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x15-input_1)^2))+
    
    
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x16-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x17-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x18-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x19-input_1)^2))+
    (n/2*log(2*pi) + n/2*log(input_2^2) + 1/(2*input_2^2) *  ((x20-input_1)^2))


fig2 = plot_ly() %>%
    add_trace(data = my_data,  x=my_data$input_1, y=my_data$input_2, z=my_data$f, type="mesh3d" )



fig2
```

[image]

Now the values on the plot appear more reasonable (i.e. no extreme large values like 100,000), but I am not sure if this plot is mathematically correct. For example, statistical theory tells us that the lowest point on this function (theoretically) should be at (5,5) - however, this does not appear to be the case?

**Note 3:** Also, if you use a slightly different set of points to create the grid, for example:

```
    set.seed(123)
    
    input_1 <- rnorm(10000, 5,2)
    input_2 <- rnorm(10000, 5,2)
    
    my_data = data.frame(input_1, input_2)

# recalculate "my_data$f" using the above formula (not shown here to save space)

my_data <- my_data[order(-my_data$f),]

head(my_data)


      input_1      input_2          f
2173 3.652663  0.005009791 12582759.7
4066 2.936565 -0.007581292  6524021.6
4026 7.968675 -0.006472597  4201973.3
5075 3.436135 -0.014480143  1585279.1
8349 1.566204  0.023340689   947827.4
4597 1.384440 -0.032005021   524830.2
```

**And I still think that such enormous values of the Likelihood Function are not very "likely" (excuse the pun)?**

Answer (score 1):

When you created the object `y`, you used a randomizing function. Unless you include `set.seed`, every time you execute the call to `y`, you are going to get different values.

I had to change `y` to have a count of 91, instead of 5, so that the call to create z to work. The length of `y` has to be the same length or a multiple of the length of `input_1`.

Since the square root of 91 isn't a whole number, I went with 91.

With `set.seed(3526)`

[image]

With `set.seed(3958)`

[image]

With `set.seed(1)`

[image]

Run your full script a few times and watch how the values continuously change.

---

---

#### Update: The MLE of Normal (AKA Gaussian)

There are many ways to break down this problem, so I'm not sure where yours went right or wrong. However, here is another way to model the likelihood:

```
set.seed(34) 
y = rnorm(100, 5, 5)

nd <- function(cv){ # continuous value = cv
  mu = (1/length(cv)) * sum(cv)  # ll of mu
  sigmaSq = (1/length(cv)) * sum((cv - mu)^2) # ll of var
  p1 = -(1/2) * log(2 * pi * sigmaSq) 
  p2 = -(1/2) * (((cv - mu)^2)/sigmaSq)
  return(p1 + p2)
}

plot_ly(x = y, y = nd(y), type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
```

[image]

I'm not sure if that's what you're aiming for, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Kat! The problem is - as far as I understand, the likelihood function of a normal distribution can never take such large values. When I evaluate the function, I get the correct answer. But the value on the graph does not seem to match (e.g. 59 vs 100,000). Do you know why this might be? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ Kat: I made some edits to the question!

Comment: @ Kat: Would you have any idea about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625643/r-different-ways-to-name-matrices thank you so much!